# magento config systems files confusion

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have confused with magento config systems. In etc directory there are some config files like config.xml, system.xml, adminhtml.xml. why magento have more than one config files? And if we need add some field in admin section some where we used php codes like:

```
$fieldset->addField('uploaded_file', 'fileuploader', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('fileuploader')->__('File'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'uploaded_file',
));
```

and some where we used xml config like

```
<sender translate="label comment">
<label>Sender</label>
<comment>Name of the sender</comment>
<validate>required-entry</validate>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                                 
<sort_order>10</sort_order>                         
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>                        
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>                            
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</sender>
```

in fields section.

Why didn't we should use all areas common configuration php orelse xml? Please explain any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mangento merges all config files needed into one big config file and stores
this one in the config cache.

Now, if we only have one config file, magento would be forced to load config data, that is not needed in the current area (frontend, admin, api) and would slow magento down.

Only the config.xml is loaded always, all other config *.xml files are loaded on demand.

In the frontend for example its no needed to load the system.xml or the adminhtml.xml since the contain only data use in the backend.

In addition if you now the purpose of each config file, its easy to find what you need.

To your second question, i think you are referring to the system configuration,
stored in system.xml under system->configuration and admin pages created by individual modules.

With the the field configuration in the xml field, you can create input fields, that will set config variables, since this is a vary basic process and there is not much space for modification, it can be configured via xml.

For you individual modules, like in you example a file upload, its already getting more complicated. Consider all the possibilities in a file upload, where to store, which file types are allow, is there a max size, maybe you want to do some other checks or save the file name in the database.
To make it more clear, try to imagine the xml that would be needed to define the admin page of "Edit Product"

If you want to know more about this topic:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_tutorial this is a good start

Answer (score 1):

Magento is modular, therefore each module has configurations.

So each module will have an `etc/` folder with one or more xml files.

Then there are system setups to access the database found in `app/etc/`

On top of that, you can have a `local.xml` file in your template `layout/` folder that can be used to fine tune, completely change or suppress various functions.

Using all areas in `app/code/core` means that the first Magento version upgrade will be quite humorous for you as all your changes get overwritten. So it's a good idea to keep your configuration changes to modules found in `app/code/core/` in custom modules you create to override any configurations found in the core or in `app/code/local/Mage` module `etc` folders.